# How to build responsive Grid in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-gridview

I want to build a grid with some images and captions in Flutter Web.
I want that in mobile it will show 2 column and in desktop 4.
How can I build this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LayoutBuilder` to establish a cut point at your desired width. Inside LayoutBuilder, set the number of columns for the grid with something like:

```
final columns = constraints.width > 500 ? 4 : 2;
```

Then build your grid within that.  You could even make it a formula, like divide the width by 250 and truncate to an int.